# download php is always damaged

Tags: php

I have a download script written in PHP. My view file script links to the ids and then selects all the data that matches the ID.

The data is then used to download the photo. Does it matter that my photo is in a folder? It is moved to a folder and then the directory is uploaded to the MYSQL database.

The code at the moment now allows some files to download perfectly and then the majority to be damaged. Any reason why?

```
    Mysql table info...
    $cool = $_GET['id'];

  $sql = "SELECT id, type, name, size FROM upload WHERE id='$cool'";

   $result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
   $data = mysql_result($result, 0, "id");
   $name = mysql_result($result, 0, "name");
   $size = mysql_result($result, 0, "size");
   $type = mysql_result($result, 0, "type");

   header("Content-type: $type");
   header("Content-length: $size");
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
   header("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data");
   header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
   header('Expires: 0');
   header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
   header('Pragma: public');
   ob_clean();
   flush();
   readfile($name);
   exit();
```

Comment: remove those nasty @'s

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: and if you have to mysql, at least DON'T use mysql_result. what's wrong with `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); echo $row['data']`?

Comment: Your code is wide open to mysql injection attacks!

Answer (score 1):

This happens because PHP send some information after you echo the data, the solution to this is to stop processing right after you echoed the data, for this add `exit();` right after `echo $data`.

Comment: data at the end of a file generally doesn't hurt too much. but data inserted at the FRONT of the file usually kills it. @NoahSmith: open the downloaded file in a text/hex editor and look for php warnings/errors embedded within the file.

Comment: @MarcB, Text files are not hurt much by it, but binary files are unreadable. But yes a nice hex editor may help you, or also viewing the file on Notepad++