# Damaged File Download PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [download php is always damaged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461417/download-php-is-always-damaged)

In my code, I can download a file but it mostly results in a damaged file etc. I am really stuck and has anyone any idea how I can improve my code. My images/documents are stored in the folder 'lessons'

They download and there is one image a 'png' which downloads perfectly, but uploading similar PNG files results in damaged files.

```
    $cool = $_GET['id'];

   $sql = "SELECT id, type, name, size FROM upload WHERE id='$cool'";

 $result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
 $data = mysql_result($result, 0, "id");
 $name = mysql_result($result, 0, "name");
  $size = mysql_result($result, 0, "size");
  $type = mysql_result($result, 0, "type");

 header("Content-type: $type");
 header("Content-length: $size");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
  header("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data");
 header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Expires: 0');
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
 header('Pragma: public');
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($name);
exit();
```

Comment: Do not open duplicate questions just because your first one didn't receive attention. Fix your preview question instead!

Comment: Poor structure AND it's difficult to see what is being asked here, please mark some answers, you have 14 questions without any answers marked as positive and you have poor question structure, review the FAQ please or stop poluting Stack Overflow

Answer (score -1):

1. Read up on SQL injection and/or move to PDO or MySQLi. Standard MySQL functions have been deprecated for that very reason.
2. This error could come from a large number of possible issue. You're pulling the file name and size from the DB - are they really matching? Are you sure the file even exists? (you're not checking - and therefore, the output of it might just be an error message telling you the file doesn't exist)
   What do you get if you open your corrupted download using notepad? Chances are you will find a PHP error in there.

I will not be any more precise until the original question has been edited.